# When a card says "you may choose new targets for the copy", do you have to choose new targets?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

For example, can you use [Pyromancer's Goggles](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=398427)' ability to use a spell twice on a single target creature or player? Like, can my opponent cast [Chandra's Fury](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=398632) on me twice for 8 damage?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, that's what "may" means: you *may* choose new targets for the copy, but if you don't, it keeps the original target.

One of the many rulings [on the Gatherer page for Pyromancer's Goggles](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=398427) says as much:

> The copy will have the same targets as the spell it’s copying unless you choose new ones. You may change any number of the targets, including all of them or none of them. If, for one of the targets, you can’t choose a new legal target, then it remains unchanged (even if the current target is illegal).